# Scaling Axis with D3 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, scaling, axes

I have plotted the X and Y axes. I have couple of points to show on the axis. My points vary for X axis from 4.5 to 8 and for Y axis from 2 to 4.

You can find the [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/6z2Trs0AZWEUhNFwDUFW?p=preview) of what I have done.

```
function kmeans(){
    x_means[0] = 5.9;

    plotMeans();
}
```

The problem is this chart shows the points such as 0.59. However, I can't see when I give the value of 5.9 since it falls out of the chart.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect your javascript console, you'll see this error:

```
Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cy="NaN"
```

This is because the data you feed d3 is:

```
> numeric.transpose([[0.59],[]])
    Array[2]
      0: 0.59
      1: undefined
```

So that:

```
.attr("cy", function(d, i){return Y(d[1]);});
```

is an operation on undefined.

**EDITS**

Do'h, just re-read your question.  Your scales need a **domain**, this is the user space span of your coordinate space.  The **range** then is is the pixel span of your coordinate space.  The scale maps the two together:

```
var X = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]) //<-- 0 to 960 pixels
    .domain([0,10]); //<-- maps to coordinates 0 to 10
```

See update [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ylal6n0k7wqYrItIEb3m?p=preview).

I also modified it to use proper axis so it's easier to visualize.

Comment: thank you. How am I supposed to change the data I feed to d3? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I think it is because of this line: `var components = svg.selectAll("line.ax")
        .data([
            [[0.0, 0.5], [1, 0.5], "X"],
            [[0.5, 0.0], [0.5, 1], "Y"]
        ], function(d, i){return d[2];});` but I don't know how I am supposed to change these data values.

Comment: Your lines draw fine.  It's your circle that's the problem.  You never assign any value to `y_means`...

Comment: You are right @Mark . I have updated the **DEMO**. But my problem is, for instance, when I give the values `x_means[0] = 5.9; y_means[0] = 2.7`, these values don't appear on the graph.

Comment: @supaplex, I'm not sure what you are asking?  When you say "values", you want axis values?  See this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ylal6n0k7wqYrItIEb3m?p=preview).

Comment: @supalex, do'h, just re-read your question, I understand.  See updated answer.

Comment: I have asked another question related to this one @Mark . You can check it from here if you are interested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209939/d-join-is-not-a-function-error-d3-javascript