# SVG append causes d.join error on D3 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to draw axes on a graph but when I append svg with g with the following line, I receive an error of `TypeError: d.join is not a function`:

```
svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height / 2 + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);
```

However, when I delete these lines, error disappears. Any ideas on how to solve this? Here is the [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wm6nxsaZwaBc1jzjpufN?p=preview).

Thank you!

Comment: They have a domain, I will update the question. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The error message actually tells you exactly where the error is coming from (and it's unrelated to the axes). It looks like you're expecting to be passed an array in `polygon()` and you aren't.

Comment: your "d" in return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z"; when logged is 0 and not an array as expected.

Comment: Original example can be found here: http://bl.ocks.org/hardbyte/ded34566f6fb704264b4 I haven't changed anything else than adding axis domains and appending g to SVG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is causing the problem:

```
var path = svg.selectAll("path");
```

This is selecting all the `path` elements of the svg.  When you add the axis, they also contain path elements that are being selected but **aren't** part of the voronoi.  The solution is to make this selector more specific:

```
var path = svg.selectAll(".step"); //<-- select by class "step" 

function redraw() {
    var d = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        d.push([X(x_means[i]), Y(y_means[i])]);
    }
    var vd = voronoi(d);
    var v = path
            .data(vd, polygon);

    v.exit().remove();

    v.enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr('class','step'); //<-- when you add a voroni path give it that class
```

Updated example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6CLWNZjRqNYFJMeFrMoR?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you very much @Mark I have asked another question on this example, you can find it here if you are interested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214572/adding-tooltip-to-circle-with-d3-javascript Thanks again!